# How to create two different firewall rules with the same ID and name that applies to different profiles using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, system-administration

I'm trying to create firewall rules that have same name, but applies to different profile.

Like this

[image]

If I use this command
`Set-NetFirewallRule -ID <Rule ID> -Profile Public -Enabled True -ErrorAction Stop`

It changes the entire rule to only have Public in its Profiles property.

How can I have two separate entity that would have the same name?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `Set-NetFirewallProfile`.
Ex: `Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled True`

Comment: This will enable the rule on all profiles. I'd like to disable it on Domain,Private and enable it on Public.

Comment: Understood. I was providing an example of the command.  You can adjust accordingly. Attached Microsoft [Set-NetFirewallProfile page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netfirewallprofile?view=windowsserver2022-ps) for reference.

Comment: I'm not following. If I pipe that command after `Get-NetFirewallRule` it will only modify the current profile on that firewall rule. It will not apply to only one profile and leave the others. Perhaps you can give an example?